# nest js swagger not render file picker field

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, openapi

```
    @Post('change-photo')
    @HttpCode(200)
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
    @ApiBody({
        schema: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              file: {
                type: 'string',
                format: 'binary',
              },
            },
          },
    })
    async uploadFile(
        @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
        @Req() { user }
    ) {
      const result = await this._spaceService.uploadPhoto(user.id, file)
      return result
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkhJR.png)

I can't figure out why swagger nest js doesn't render field with picker file

I tried different options but did not understand why there are no changes.
Please help)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.1",
    "@nestjsi/class-validator": "^0.0.11",
    "@types/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2": "^1.0.6",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "joi": "^17.7.0",
    "minio": "^7.0.32",
    "mongoose": "^6.9.0",
    "mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2": "^1.0.6",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.7.1",
    "nestjs-minio-client": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-custom": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out why swagger nest js doesn't render field with picker file

You need to click "Try it out" in Swagger UI in order for the file input to appear.